# Join two tables with one nullable FK

Tags: sql, join, cross-join

I try write query like this:

```
WITH
    [order_statements]
AS
(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        (
            VALUES
                (1, 1),
                (2, 1),
                (3, NULL),
                (4, 1),
                (4, 2)
        )
            AS [t1]
            (
                [OrderId],
                [OrderStatementId]
            )
),
    [statments]
AS
(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        (
            VALUES
                (1),
                (2)
        )
            AS [t1]
            (
                [StatementId]
            )
)
SELECT
    [t2].[OrderId],
    [t1].[StatementId],
    [t2].[OrderStatementId]
FROM
                [statments] AS [t1]
    CROSS JOIN
                [order_statements] AS [t2]
ORDER BY
    [t2].[OrderId],
    [t1].[StatementId]
```

In result I want:

```
| OrderId | StatementId | OrderStatementId |
|       1 |           1 |                1 |
|       1 |           2 |             NULL |
|       2 |           1 |                1 |
|       2 |           2 |             NULL |
|       3 |           1 |             NULL |
|       3 |           2 |             NULL |
|       4 |           1 |                1 |
|       4 |           2 |                2 |
```

Any idea? When in [order_statements] I have [OrderStatementId] I can marge row. If I have not in [OrderStatementId] I set NULL. The best solution is when I only one get access to table. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The cross join produces all the combinations you need. In addition to it you need to left join the original table to retrieve the extra values.

For example, you can do:

```
select
  os.OrderId,
  s.StatementId,
  o.OrderStatementId
from statments s
cross join (select distinct OrderId from order_statements) os
left join order_statements o 
   on o.OrderStatementId = s.StatementId
  and o.OrderId = os.OrderId
order by os.OrderId, s.StatementId
```

Result:

```
 OrderId  StatementId  OrderStatementId 
 -------- ------------ ---------------- 
 1        1            1                
 1        2            null             
 2        1            1                
 2        2            null             
 3        1            null             
 3        2            null             
 4        1            1                
 4        2            2
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=01f513a11fb137b124f190628e0e9516).